# Equality of real numbers whose squares sum to 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am helping a friend with homework and got stuck on the following problem.  It doesn't seem like it should be that hard, I don't know why I'm having a hard time:

For $a,b\geq0$, if $a^2+b^2=1$, then $a+b\geq1.$

Thanks.

Comment: If $a,b \geq 0$, then $2ab \geq 0$ and $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +2ab \geq a^2 +b^2 = 1$, so $(a+b)^2 \geq 1$. Now take the square root of both sides.

Comment: Oh, hey, thanks.  I actually figured it out and posted it below before I noticed that you had as well.  Thanks anyways

Comment: It's my pleasure :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the answer almost as soon as I was done typing that.  Sorry for that.  I thought I'd include the answer, just in case anyone else has the same question:

Let $a,b\geq0$.  Then $a+b\geq1$ if and only if $(a+b)^2\geq1^2=1$.  Since $a,b\geq0$, notice that since $0\leq ab\leq2ab$, adding $1$ to both sides yields
$$1\leq2ab+1=2ab+(a^2+b^2)=a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2.$$
Since $(a+b)^2\geq1$, it follows that $a+b\geq1$.

Comment: I would have done it more directly: $a$ and $b$ must both be at most $1$, thus $a \geq a^2$ and $b \geq b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a^2+b^2=1$ then $a$, $b$ and $1$ may be considered as the sides of a pythagorean triangle. Now just apply the triangle inequation.